# Can I enter the UK visa free after a visa refusal due to lack of funds?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, visa-free-entry

I have been refused a visa: can I still travel to England, and on arrival at the airport, show that I have the necessary funds? I was refused because I put incorrectly the amount of money for my stay, which is for two weeks.

I am coming from Australia and it seems I don't really need a visa. Can I just do it at on arrival at the London airport?

Comment: You're an Australian citizen? Traveling to the UK for two weeks? Why did you apply for the visa in the first place?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. The airline won't stop you because you don't need a visa. The question is whether you will be allowed in once you arrive. Australia is a long flight back if you're denied entry.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but better to fix the refusal so you're not having to explain it all the time.

Comment: I am exhibiting in an art exhibition and did not want things to go wrong so thought it may be best to make sure, and have a visa

Comment: Also, it is done through a collection agency via the UK website and then the documents are sent, you don't have access to any people physicallyl

Comment: so fixing the refusal is harder because you cannot explain to anyone, they have said it will be judged on it own merrit next time , and I have paid all ccomadatin in advance, would I need the 200 pounds a day amount, for my bank to look healthy?

Comment: @MatthewFitch we already know about the VFS (what you call 'collection agency') (Aussie applications are processed in Manilla), you have a good answer below for entering the UK but if you want to "fix" the refusal by successfully getting an entry clearance, then open a new question and upload the redacted scan of your refusal notice.

Comment: yes I have open a new question and added document scan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there are some limitations on it, namely length of stay above six months, as an Australian citizen, you do not have to apply for a visa to enter the UK. You still have to carry the same supporting documents with you to show an immigration officer at the border.

But with your recent refusal I would not recommend doing that, and instead open a new question here with a scan of your refusal. It's very easy to focus on what you think is the most important part of the refusal, and subsequently, ignore very dangerous warning signs that are also there and may put future applications in jeopardy.

You can then use the advice given here to apply again, hopefully, this time successfully. This saves you not only the process you will likely have to go through at the airport but also money in case you are denied entry.